# Confused by resolution/dpi with Retina screen

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, retina

I'm very confused by my Retina screen on the latest Macbook Pro. I edit my photos in photoshop, where they look how I want it. I edit them in 150 dpi, mostly in the size 1772 x 1173 pixels. It fit's perfectly in my screen, and they are very sharp. But when I save the photos they change, and get bigger and blurry when I see them in the original size. I'm struggling with building a website now, because when I upload the pictures there they are also so big. So what would be a good resolution to edit my pictures in photoshop so that they are the same everywhere? I'll add two screenshots with the difference.

[image: saved]

[image: in photoshop]

**edit**: I did some research, and actually I found out that it hast something to do with photoshop: http://designm.ag/photoshop-2/pixel-design-issue-photoshop-retina/. But still that doesn't solve my problem.

[image]

If I resize a picture in photoshop, it looks perfectly sharp when it's 100%. But when I save the photo it will double the size because of the retina screen, and then it's very bad. I just want large photos which look sharp and good when they are the original size, and I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with 72 DPI? 
Usually when I prepare graphics for web I don't use more than 72 DPI and for now its worked ok.

Only if I need to prepare something for printing I go for higher DPI, eg. 300 DPI.